# How to make a chart that automatically selects range based on available data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table of process measurements. Rows are measurements and columns are different variables. I have a macro that copies the data from another worksheet. The number on measurements can vary, and I'd like to write a macro that automatically selects range based on the number on measurements and plots the variable values as a function of time. I'd also like to have a macro that moves the source column of the chart one to the right, so every time that I run the macro, it plots different variable as a function of time(measurement). How should I approach this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51069806/edit) to include more information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your data in one sheet
2. Then use `rngSourceData = Sheets(index).UsedRange` to get the data automatically.
3. Draw your chart by VBA codes. The chart creation normally need the source data range as input, then pass the `rngSourceData` to the function. Such as below demo:

   ```
   Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
       SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
       SourceData:=rngSourceData, _
       Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)
   ```
4. Then you can rerun the step 2-3 and refresh the chart if your data changed.

You may record the macro codes to get the example on how to create your specific chart then change the codes a little bit.